# How to initialize redux-form fields with data received via ajax/axios api call?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I have managed to successfully pass initial values for my form fields with

```
export default reduxForm({
  form: "Item",
  initialValues: {name: "blah"}
  keepDirtyOnReinitialize: true,
  enableReinitialize: true,
  updateUnregisteredFields: true
})(Item);
```

but I am failing to pass a value which I am receiving from an action I am dispatching in componentDidMount().

How would I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

Once you receive props from reducer, map them to the value property in each field of the form.

Comment: Currently my fields all have their values set to this.formProps.value, how would I get around this?

Comment: Is value prop an object? If yes, value your fields based on the keys present in the value prop.